# $R$-orientable manifolds and some covering spaces associated to them

Tags: algebraic-topology

**I think I have solved it, but not sure however. The "solution" is in the most recent update.**

Currently I'm reading through Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, and I'm stuck on one thing in the text. At page 236, he states that if $M$ is a closed connected $n$-manifold, then if $M$ is not $R$-orientable, the map $H_n(M;R) \rightarrow H_n(M|x;R) $ is injective, with image $\{r \in R | 2r = 0 \}$. This should follow from Lemma 3.27 in the text, where he says that :

> Let M be a manifold of dimension n and let $A \subset M$ be a compact subset. Then if $x \rightarrow \alpha_x $ is a section of the covering space $M_R \rightarrow M$, then there is a unique class $\alpha_a \in H_n(M|A;R)$ whose image in $H_n(M|x;R)$ is $\alpha_x$ for all $x \in A$.

He shows that this gives an isomorphism between the set of sections $\gamma_R(M)$ and $H_n(M;R)$. Okay, I agree with that. What I don't follow is why  the theorem follows from this, and that a section is uniquely determined by its value at one point.

Any help with explaining why this is, would be appreciated.

**Update:** Still no real progress. I have, through reading Hatcher, noticed that we can identify $H_n(M|x;R)$ with $H_n(M|X) \otimes R$ (when leaving out $R$, I mean $Z$-coefficients). So, maybe a section decides a subcovering of some sort. Still, that's about it. I've thought about seeing is this covering has some automorphisms or something, but it doesn't quite seem to work.

**Yet another update!(Which I think solves it)**
Okay, I think I might have got it. Let M be a non-orientable manifold. Look at the sections $f:M \rightarrow M_R$, $-f$. A section is determined by its value at an unique point, so the image of these two sections will be $M_r = \{\pm 1 \otimes r\}$, a covering space of M. If $r$ fails to have order $2$, this will be isomorphic to the double oriented covering of M, let's call it $\hat{M}$, which is oriented. So, since $f$ is clearly bijective onto its image, continuous and with a continuous inverse, we have shown that M must be homeomorphic to a submanifold of the oriented manifold $\hat{M}$, but M was assumed not to be orientable, so $r=-r$, that is, it has order 2.